# Cannot find shared library in same directory as CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake

In my source code directory, I have a shared library file called `libAlpha.so`. Then, in my CMakeLists.txt file, I have:

```
target_link_libraries(MyProgram Alpha)
```

However, this gives me the error:

```
usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lAlpha
```

If I rename the library file to `Alpha.so` or `lAlpha.so`, I get the same error. Similarly, if I instead use the line:

```
target_link_libraries(MyProgram libAlpha)
```

or:

```
target_link_libraries(MyProgram libAlpha.so)
```

Why can cmake not find this library, even though it is in the same directory as CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Try using `link_directories` to inform the linker in which directories libraries can be found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `link_directories`.

Specify the full path to the library (possibly using `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` if that's where you have it, or use `find_library` with that path and the name (without `lib` prefix or extension) for a 'more portable' solution, though something tells me portability is not your concern...

Comment: Thanks! So, I tried `target_link_libraries(MyProgram ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libAlpha.so), which worked :)

Answer (score 2):

When you use `cmake` you usually build (and it is recommended practice) in the separate directory than were your source files and `CMakeLists.txt` file are located. So if you follow this practice (and error show you probably do) linker cannot find library located in that directory. So you either need to add it by link_directories():

```
link_directories( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} )
```

or you can set a property to the lib:

```
add_library( Alpha DYNAMIC IMPORTED )
set_property( TARGET Alpha PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libAlpha.so )
```

if `CMakeLists.txt` where you put those commands located not in the same directory, you can add path:

```
link_directories( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foobar )
link_directories( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/.. )
```

just remember that variable `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` is set to path where that `CMakeLists.txt` is located.

Comment: Any idea, why the line `add_library(googletest DYNAMIC IMPORTED)` results in a `Cannot find source file: DYNAMIC Tried extensions .c .C .c++ ...` ?

Answer (score 0):

> If I rename the library file to Alpha.so or lAlpha.so, I get the same error.

Yes, that won't help at all. If the library is called `libAlpha.so` then `-lAlpha` tells the linker to use it, so cmake is using the right option and the problem is not with the name of the library.

> Why can cmake not find this library, even though it is in the same directory as CMakeLists.txt?

Because the current directory has no special meaning to the linker (nor does the directory CMakeLists.txt is in, because the linker knows nothing about cmake at all).

You need to add the directory to the linker's search path, which is done with the `-L` option. I don't know how to tell cmake to use that option, but a quick look at the cmake docs suggests it is probably `link_directories` e.g. use `link_directories(.)` to add `-L.` to the linker command.

Comment: @Slava, that's why I said that adds -L. to the linker command, not that it refers to the directory containing the CMakeLists.txt file